Hashicorp Consul OIDC authentication and auditlog
I'm using HashiCorp Consul with Keycloak for OpenID Connect (OIDC) authentication. I have encountered an issue when enabling audit logs. When I log in to Consul, the logs display the temporary token ID and token description, but there is no information about the LDAP user who logged in. As a result, I cannot determine who logged in and which token ID belongs to whom.
Is there a way to add extra fields to the Consul audit logs to include user-related information, such as the LDAP username?
